# Rewrite with multiple symfony projects under same directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony

I'm trying to make some personal projects in my development server, like some sort of intranet.

If I divide each project in a different virtualhost, I set in each computer the host file to each server name and I don't have problems with the rewrite rule and the app.php. But the problem is that I can't modify the host file in an android device so I can't access those webs.

What I have in mind is something like this:

I have three symfony projects under my home folder

```
/home/user/projects/project1
/home/user/projects/project2
/home/user/projects/project3
```

Then, under the default folder of apache I make soft links to the web folder to every project:

```
ln -s /home/user/projects/project1/web /var/www/html/project1
ln -s /home/user/projects/project2/web /var/www/html/project2
ln -s /home/user/projects/project3/web /var/www/html/project3
```

So I can access them this way:

```
http://server-ip/project1
http://server-ip/project2
http://server-ip/project3
```

The problem is that I use those url I need to add the default app.php. I've been trying to modify the  .htaccess file of each project, but I don't what to modify. I'm using the default virtualhost configuration and the default .htaccess file of each project.

I think that I need to modify the RewriteCond line, but I don't know what to do.

Thanks

Comment: Still you can create vhosts with different ports and access to them from external devices as `http://server-ip:8001/` for project1 `http://server-ip:8002/` for project2 and so on.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I said that I'm doing it like an intranet, but if on another projects I want to access from outside my network I need to open those ports in the router too. Alister solution worked for what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a local development environment (it's actually running on a linux server, under my desk, but the same setup would apply to any other configuration of server).

The webserver has a local IP address, reachable from elsewhere on the local network, including from my phone over WiFi.

All the development sites have their own Vhost configured on the server, with a common DNS prefix - something like `*.devserver.domain.com`.

The DNS is configured so that `devserver.domain.com` and the wildcard `*.devserver.domain.com` return 192.168.1.75 (or whatever the internal, static IP address is). This is a public domain name that has an A record to a local-range IP address, but it's entirely valid.

If you don't have a domain name that you can add wildcard DNSs to, you can use a service such as http://nip.io/ - and so the vhost Servername would be something like:

- project1.192.168.1.75.nip.io
- project2.192.168.1.75.nip.io
- ... etc

You may end up regularly editing the apache vhost if you internal IP changes at all, and maybe finding alternate wildcard DNS servers (my go-to was xip.io, but that isn't diffcult to do).

You may also be able to use an internal wildcard for an Apache ServerName/serverAlias: `ServerAlias mysite.*.xip.io`.

Comment: Yes, that worked. I used the tk domains, they are free. They don't admit the wild card *, but they allow to insert several domains, and for now they are enough. Thanks!